# How to call Delphi DLL from C# (Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible error)?

Tags: c#, delphi, dll

I have some Delphi code which is currently calling a DLL (also written in Delphi). Here is the Delphi code:

```
    TDLLDataHeader = record
        s                   : string[255];
        i                   : integer;
        stage               : integer;
        number_of_fields    : integer;
        sample_code         : string[255];
        comment             : string[255];
    end;

    TPassword_rec = record
        level               : byte;
        User_ID             : string[20];
        Signature           : string[80];
    end;

    TField_result  = packed record        {Packed added to make size compatible with Delphi4}
        area                        : double;
        count                       : longint;
        frame_area                  : double;
        perimeter                   : double;  { currently 0}
        total_object_grey_level     : comp;
        total_framed_grey_level     : comp;
        pixel_area                  : comp;
        pixel_frame_area            : comp;
        mean_object_grey_level      : double;
        mean_framed_grey_level      : double;
        no_of_excluded_objects      : longint;
        ppm                         : double;
        total_ppm                   : double;
        ppm_squared                 : double;
    end;

    Tfeature_summary  = packed record  {Packed added to make size compatible with Delphi4}
        total_eba              : double;
        eba_ppm                : double;
        eba_ppm_squared        : double;
        total_object_area      : double;
        total_perimeter        : double;
        total_grey_level       : longint;
        ppm                    : double;
        total_ppm              : double;
        ppm_squared            : double;
    end;

    Tshortmeasurement   = record
        sample_code              : string[255];
        comment                  : string[255];
        datetime                 : Tdatetime;
        measured_by              : string[20];
        dilution                 : double;
        calibration_factor_used  : double;
        field                    : Tfield_result;
        feature                  : Tfeature_summary;
        detection_mode           : integer; {25/8/00 detection settings added to measurement data}
        straight_threshold       : byte;
        matrix_threshold         : byte;
        matrix_size              : byte;
        Count_per_plate          : integer;
    end;

procedure GetDLLData_header(var Aheaderdata : PDllDataHeader); stdcall; external 'remote.dll' name 'GetDLLData';
          { reads global data pointer back fronm the dll}
function get_data : Tshortmeasurement; stdcall; external 'remote.dll' name 'get_data';
function get_macro_status : byte; stdcall; external 'remote.dll' name 'get_macro_status';
function send_msg_to_host(lparam,wparam : longint) : longint; stdcall; external 'remote.dll' name 'send_msg_to_host';
function get_no_of_measurements : integer; stdcall; external 'remote.dll' name 'get_no_of_measurements';
```

Further on in the Delphi code there is a call to get_data:

```
var
    Temp_data : Tshortmeasurement;
begin
    temp_data := get_data;
end;
```

I am trying to recreate this in C# but I am getting a "Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible error".

Here is my C# code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
public struct TField_result
{
    //area                        : double;
    public double area;
    //count                       : longint;
    public int count;
    //frame_area                  : double;
    public double frame_area;
    //perimeter                   : double;  { currently 0}
    public double perimeter;
    //total_object_grey_level     : comp;
    public double total_object_grey_level;
    //total_framed_grey_level     : comp;
    public double total_framed_grey_level;
    //pixel_area                  : comp;
    public double pixel_area;
    //pixel_frame_area            : comp;
    public double pixel_frame_area;
    //mean_object_grey_level      : double;
    public double mean_object_grey_level;
    //mean_framed_grey_level      : double;
    public double mean_framed_grey_level;
    //no_of_excluded_objects      : longint;
    public int no_of_excluded_objects;
    //ppm                         : double;
    public double ppm;
    //total_ppm                   : double;
    public double total_ppm;
    //ppm_squared                 : double;
    public double ppm_squared;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
public struct TFeature_summary
{
    //total_eba              : double;
    public double total_eba;
    //eba_ppm                : double;
    public double eba_ppm;
    //eba_ppm_squared        : double;
    public double eba_ppm_squared;
    //total_object_area      : double;
    public double total_object_area;
    //total_perimeter        : double;
    public double total_perimeter;
    //total_grey_level       : longint;
    public int total_grey_level;
    //ppm                    : double;
    public double ppm;
    //total_ppm              : double;
    public double total_ppm;
    //ppm_squared            : double;
    public double ppm_squared;
}


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Tshortmeasurement
{
    //sample_code              : string[255];
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 255)]
    public string sample_code;
    //comment                  : string[255];
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 255)]
    public string comment;
    //datetime                 : Tdatetime;
    public double datetime;
    //measured_by              : string[20];
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 20)]
    public string measured_by;
    //dilution                 : double;
    public double dilution;
    //calibration_factor_used  : double;
    public double calibration_factor_used;
    //field                    : Tfield_result;
    public TField_result field;
    //feature                  : Tfeature_summary;
    public TFeature_summary feature;
    //detection_mode           : integer;
    public int detection_mode;
    //straight_threshold       : byte;
    public byte straight_threshold;
    //matrix_threshold         : byte;
    public byte matrix_threshold;
    //matrix_size              : byte;
    public byte matrix_size;
    //Count_per_plate          : integer;
    public int Count_per_plate;
}


class Program
{


    [DllImport("remote.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern UIntPtr send_msg_to_host(
        IntPtr lParam,
        UIntPtr wParam
    );
    [DllImport("remote.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int get_no_of_measurements();

    [DllImport("remote.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern Tshortmeasurement get_data();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = get_no_of_measurements();
        get_data();
        Console.WriteLine(n.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The call to get_no_of_measurements works fine, but the call to get_data results in the error mentioned previously. I have researched about "marshalling" and I think that must be the cause, possibly relating to the TFeature_summary and TField_result structs. I am fairly new to C# so apologies if I have missed something obvious!

Comment: I think the issue is with public TField_result field; and  public TFeature_summary feature;  Both arre pointer to structures and should be label in c# with [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]  I believe they are being implemented as in-line instead of pointers.  I also suspect issue with treating DateTime as a double. You may just want to treat it as 8 bytes.  If the DateTime is unix it starts at 1/1/ 1970 while c# treats start date as 1/1/1900.  So temporally handling as 8 bytes will prevent a conversion error.  Then once you get working then you can correct the conversion.

Comment: @jdweng is wrong here in numerous ways. This is a question that requires knowledge of Delphi. `LPStruct` isn't going to help here, because the Delphi ABI for large struct return values is different from C#. Large struct return values are treated as implicit `var` params, after all other params. The Delphi `TDateTime` is a double value measured in seconds after the COM epoch. Delphi `Comp` is a 64 bit integer type held in a floating point value. You can't p/invoke it. Delphi `string[N]` is a shortstring, which has an initial byte containing the string length.

Comment: In short it is not tractable for you to call this Delphi DLL directly without doing a lot of manual marshalling. That is possible. However it is awkward. Change the interface, either by modifying the Delphi code, or if you cannot by using an adapter Delphi DLL.

Comment: What I said i accurate.  I have no idea what David is saying.  As I said the date time is 8 bytes which is 64 bits so I don't know why David is saying I'm wrong like he always does.  All David says it is wrong with no solution.  The DateTime conversion is pretty simple without doing any marshaling it can be handle in c# code.  Saying that the LPStruct is after the return values is actual a pointer like I said.  I can easily get this code to work provided that the Delphi is using windows allocation for TField_result and  Tfeature_summary which is the only way the Delphi could work.

Comment: @jdweng You suggested that `TDateTime` is a 64 bit UNIX time. It's not. it's what I said it is. Which is confirmed by the documentation. What I said about Delphi shortstring is accurate. Confirmed by the documentation. What I said about the return type being treated as a `var` param by Delphi is accurate. Confirmed by the documentation. The sub records `TField_result` and `Tfeature_summary` are not pointers. This is easily confirmed by using the Delphi `SizeOf` operator. The `Comp` type is also documented.

Comment: Thanks both for your comments. I am unable to make it work, being both a novice in Delphi and C#. Maybe my next step will then be to modify the DLL to send some simpler data which will help diagnose the issue.

Comment: This is advanced level stuff. You want to start small and work up. Classic novice mistake not to realise how hard a problem is. That's fine. Just start with something simple and build up. Be prepared for it to take time.